# How do I create an array of Objects in Processing [Literally]?

Tags: java, processing

I want to know how to literally put an object in an array, ex:

```
TreeObj[] trees = {new TreeObj(100,100), new TreeObj(50,50)};
```

Where the first value is x and the second value is y. I have looked this up before but got responses such as this:

```
TreeObj[] trees = new TreeObj[2];
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about exactly what you mean by "the first value is x and the second value is y"? Shameless self-promotion: please see [this tutorial](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/arrays) on arrays in Processing.

Answer (score 0):

Both options are valid.

Option one is instantiating the objects in one go, which is a little less verbose, but won't allow you do easily pass dynamic parameters to the constructor:

```
TreeObj[] trees = {new TreeObj(100,100), new TreeObj(50,50)};

void setup(){
  for(TreeObj t : trees) t.draw();
}

class TreeObj{
  int x,y;

  TreeObj(int x,int y){
    println(x,y);
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  void draw(){
    ellipse(x,y,20,20);
  }
}
```

Option two create the array of that length with that class type, but the array will contain two `null` values until you initalise each with a new instance of that class, but you can pass dynamic parameters to the constructor:

```
TreeObj[] trees = new TreeObj[2];

void setup(){
  print("trees[] before instantiation: ");
  println(trees);

  for(int i = 0 ; i < trees.length; i++){
    trees[i] = new TreeObj(width/(i+1),height/(i+1));
    trees[i].draw();
  }

  print("trees[] after instantiation: ");
  println(trees);
}

class TreeObj{
  int x,y;

  TreeObj(int x,int y){
    println(x,y);
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  void draw(){
    ellipse(x,y,20,20);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

An array of objects works the same way as any array. Both ways are perfectly fine, it really depends on what you want to do. The first way is in a sense a 'shortcut' create and initialize the array. The second way would make the space in heap memory, and then you would have to do something like:

```
trees[0] = new TreeObj(100,100);
trees[1] = new TreeObj(50,50);
```

I think the first way is mostly used for when you only have limited values that you know of eg limited moves you may want to loop over but never modify:

```
int[][] moves = { {-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, -1} }; //creates 4 x 2 array
```

whereas the second way is usually initialized using loops. An example would be creating a map that a player would move on. You may want a 100 x 100 map. And then you choose to fill it up with characters first, like ' '. And then when the player moves, the character changes to '.'. Obviously, you won't hardcode the entire thing so you do something like:

```
char[][] map= new char[100][100]; //creates 100 x 100 array
for(int i = 0; i < map.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; i < map[i].length; j++){
        map[i][j] = ' '; //initialization of array, changing default
    }
}
```

An Object array is just changing the type of array. So instead of int or char, you have a TreeObj array. Note that by using the second method, the array is initialized to its defaults, so for int it would be full of 0s and for wrappers/ objects, it would bee full of nulls (I realized I used 2D arrays as my examples. The logic/ concept holds true for 1D array as well). So, in conclusion, it really depends on how you plan to use the array!